# Is there any HTML element or Plugin available to get both Text and image together as input?

Tags: html

I am developing a Student Self Assessment Application using HTML&JSP for UI...I have a question bank page where the admin can login and pre populate the Questions & Answers. Students will be provided with these Questions to answer....

It is required that the admin should be able to enter  both text and image as input for Questions in the Questions TextBox....Because  topics like maths,physics include small figures & diagrams in Question & solution part....

Is there any element / Script / Plugin available to handle this scenario....

Comment: A rich text editor will probably be as close as you get, for example [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/)

Comment: Thank you . it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think CKeditor is what you are looking For [Go Here](https://ckeditor.com/) And Take A look.

Answer (score 0):

Usual text input and textarea doesn't support image input, but you can add separate image input (type="file").

Step 1: add onchange on the file input and take event

Step 2: create a link from event - URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])

Step 3: create img tag with a src={link above} to show it right after changing

Step 4: after sending form-data request, create image URL in the back-end

Step 5: after getting data from the back-end just show your text with an image below.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is TinyMCE
https://www.tiny.cloud/

[Check out a demo](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/)

[Here is image integration](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/image-tools/) which may potentially require a paid license if you can't host your own version

Comment: Thank you . it helped a lot